# C# Repositories and Http responses not returning expected data using same dbContext XUnit

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

I've been trying to implement integration tests with a database per test strategy, but I haven't been able to make it work as needed.

1. This is the factory class that uses WebApplicationFactory:

   ```
    public class TestFactory<TProgram, TDbContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    where TProgram : class where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.RemoveDbContext<TDbContext>();
                services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                });

                services.EnsureDbCreated<TDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
   ```
2. This is the TestClass:

   ```
    public class RolesControllerTest : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TestFactory<Program, ADbContext> _factory;
        private IServiceScope  _scope;
        private ADbContext_dbContext;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private IRoleRepository _rolesRepository;

        public RolesControllerTest()
        {
            _factory = new TestFactory<Program, ADbContext>();
            _client = _factory.CreateClient();

            _scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = _scope.ServiceProvider;
            _dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ADbContext>();
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _factory.Dispose();
            _scope.Dispose();
        }

      // Tests ...
    }
   ```
3. This is the test:

   ```
        [Fact(DisplayName = "GetAsync returns a list of role models")]
        public async Task GetAsync_ReturnsTaskOfRoleModelList()
        {
            var roleModelInDb = new RoleModel
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Role A",
                Description = "Role A Description"
            };

             _rolesRepository = new RoleRepository(_dbContext, TestMapperHelper.GenerateTestMapper());
            var roleModel = await _rolesRepository.CreateAsync(roleModelInDb);

            var responseData = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<RoleModel>>("/api/roles");

            responseData.ShouldNotBeNull();
            responseData.ShouldBeOfType<List<RoleModel>>();
            responseData.Count.ShouldBe(1);
            responseData[0].Id.ShouldBe(roleModel.Id);
            responseData[0].Name.ShouldBe(roleModelInDb.Name);
        }
   ```

The repository returns the expected data: the new roleModel that's been added to the db.
The responseData is a list as expected, but it's empty, so the test fails.

If I try to use a client instead of the repository to create the initial roleModel:

```
   var createdResponse = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/roles", roleModelInDb);
   var createdByClient = await TestResponseHelper.GetResponseContent<RoleModel>(createdResponse);
```

The createdResponse is a 200 OK Http response, and the role model createdByClient is a valid RoleModel, but the test fails, the list is still empty.

If I use a roleRepository to find the previously created roleModel by Id, the result is null.

If I'm using the same database context for the web factory and repositories, why is this happening?

Comment: Without all of your code, this is hard to answer because there could be plenty of reasons (e. g. `SaveChangesAsync()` could be missing inside `RoleRepository`, etc.). So it would be great if you could provide a complete example (e. g. as a GitHub repo or add all your classes here). If that's not possible, I'd check whether you're actually using the same databases (check for `Guid.NewGuid()` inside the `api/roles` controller.